# Need to verify text in table cell using Selenium Wrapper for Visual Basic

Tags: excel, vba, selenium

I am using the Selenium Wrapper for Visual Basic to automate a Chrome browser.

I need to verify text in a table based on a string in a previously stored string variable (invoice).

Simplified HTML example:

```
<th scope="row" class=" dataCell  ">
<a href="link-to-follow" onclick="searchResultClick.mousedown(this, event)" onmousedown="searchResultClick.mousedown(this, event)">Link Text</a>
</th>
<td class=" dataCell  ">Text to be verified</td>
<td class=" dataCell  ">&nbsp;</td>
```

I've tried this in Excel VBA to no avail:

```
Sub SearchForInvoice()
Dim driver As New SeleniumWrapper.WebDriver
Dim invoice As String
invoice = "Text to be verified"
If driver.verifyTextPresent(invoice) = True Then
   MsgBox("Success")
Else
End If
End Sub
```

An error message shows up saying "Runtime Error '13': Type mismatch"

Thanks in advance for any help that can be offered. Still fairly new to programming.

Comment: Which line throws exception?

Comment: @Saifur the line:
`If driver.verifyTextPresent(invoice) = True Then`
is giving me the problem

Answer (score 0):

It has been long time I wrote any `VBA` code. However yours problem look simple.

```
Sub SearchForInvoice()
    Dim driver As New SeleniumWrapper.WebDriver
    Dim invoice As String

    invoice = "Text to be verified"

    'You are doing driver.verifyTextPresent on driver itself. It should be on an element instead.
    'Or, simply finding the element with text based xpath search is enough as well.

    If driver.findElementByXPath("//td[.='Text to be verified']").size() > 0 Then

       MsgBox("Success")

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried `If driver.findElementByXPath("//d[.=invoice]").Size() > 0 Then` but I get an error message saying "Compile error: Type mismatch" which then highlights the ">". Do you know why this is happening?

Comment: Actually do `driver.findElementsByXPath("//td[.='Text to be verified']").size() > 0`

Comment: Sorry, not very familiar with Seleniium `VBA`